# Error in stored procedure but no error when running it manually

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that creates a xml file. When I run it, I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'some text here' to int

If I put the same code in the query window in SSMS and execute it, it works fine - no error.

Can someone tell me why could that happen? The procedure is long enough to post it here, it's mainly a huge select with lots of unions and joins.

Thank you!

Comment: seems like your string is not a valid number

Comment: Indeed, it is not. But why does in not throw an error when run manually?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You are obviously using a string and treating it like a number. Most likely it is an implicit conversion. Perhaps if you could share the procedure at the very least we could help. As it sits right now there is no chance anybody can help.

Comment: how do you run it manualy and how the other way? and like Sean said, probably somewhere is a implicit conversion going on

Comment: Unfortunatelly I cannot share the procedure. I just hoped someone might give an idea why error in procedure, and no error in the query window. Same code, same database.

Comment: I run both in SSMS. Right click on procedure and execute -> error. Code in query window, execute -> no error.

Comment: Well since you can't share you proc there isn't much we can do. Look for datatype conversions. Try to find the actual text that is throwing the error as a place to start.

Comment: I've already found the text in the table but no idea yet why it tries to convert it to int. Will have to dig deeper in that absolutely huge select. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Are you joining that column in there to a column that is an int? That is a pretty common reason this can happen.

Comment: Not sure. The select phrase is very big and it contains a lot of functions that return values from tables. Wanted to print it but gave up when I saw it's 95 pages. It will take a while to understand what the coder did there.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in one of the columns in your join is comparing a varchar to an integer, and at least one of the varchar values is not an integer.

So try the following test:

```
select *
    from table
    where myCol NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

and perhaps

```
select *
    from table
    where CONVERT (bigint, myCol) NOT BETWEEN -2147483648 AND 2147483647
```

Shake the tree and see what falls off.